# How to remove "Archives" from the meta title of CPT archive page in sage? Roots.io

Tags: wordpress, roots-sage

I am using wordpress with sage theme and would like delete the term “Archives:” from the meta title of CPT archive page.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/

> CPT Title Without word: ‘Archive’: If you are building custom archive
>   template for a CPT, and want to output just the title of the CPT with
>   no extra word like “Archive” use following function instead:

```
echo post_type_archive_title( '', false );
```